# setTimeOut is not waiting for proper delay time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons play and stop. When I click play I want the images to run like a slideshow.
I am using `setTimeout()` and having it wait 5 seconds before running.

When play is clicked, the code runs fine , waiting for 5 seconds and then displaying the next image, but when I click stop , and then click play again, it stops waiting the correct interval.Instead of waiting for 5 seconds before running, it waits for one second for the first two images and then 5 seconds for the next, again for one second for the next two and so on..

Why is it running correctly the first time and then breaking on retry?

**Code:**

```
var stop = false;
playClickfunction() {
    showImages();
}
showImages() {
    //code to display image for all no of images
    //and user can stop on any no of image..
    if(!stop)
       setTimeout(showImages, 5000);
}

stopClickfunction() {
   stop = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to clear the Timeout on stop.

maybe try something like that:

```
var timer = false;

playClickfunction()
{
    showImages();
}

showImages()
{

    //code to display image for all no of images
    //and user can stop on any no of image..
    if(!stop)
       timer = setTimeout(showImages, 5000);
}

stopClickfunction()
{

   clearTimeout( timer )
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working properly now.. you saved my lot of time. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the proper way than with a flag variable

```
var timer = setTimeout(showImages, 5000);
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the method clearTimeOut() for that

Answer (score 0):

If you click stop, then click start again before the 5 seconds has elapsed, the first timeout will keep running. What you need to do is clear the timeout, not just to stop the images, but every time start is clicked, e.g.:

```
var timeout;

function start() {
    stop();
    showImages();
  }
}

function stop() {

  if (timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
  }
}

function showImages() {
  // do stuff, then
  timeout = setTimeout(showImages, 5000);
}
```

Alternatively, if start is clicked and the timeout is set, just ignore the click since the timer is already running. In that case you'd do:

```
function start() {
  if (!timeout) {
    showImages();
  }
}
```